# Firebase - secure location to be targeted with query

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Hello guys,

I started to work on securing my Firebase. I have a location containing a list of events :

```
events:
    $event1: {
        name: test
        ...
    }
    $event2: {
        name: test2
        ...
    }
```

In my app, I let the user add events using their name. For that, after the user validates his input (eventName), I'm looking if that name exists using

```
ref.child("events").orderByChild("name").equalTo(eventName)
```

And if so, I will add it to the list of user's events. My issue is with security. If I define security rules like so :

```
"events": {
  "$eventId": {
    ".read": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Then it fails - it's completely expected since "events" location, which is targeted by the Firebase reference, has no "read" rule. The problem is, I don't want to open the "events" location for read by all connected users, since events are private and must be shared directly by their name.

So, since this name must be unique, I could use it as the event object key in place of the Firebase generated key (I currently use .push() when a new event is created to add it to the list, Firebase generates me the key), but I really like the way it is now. So I ask before changing : is there another way to reach what I'm aiming to do ?

Thanks a lot ahead.

Comment: The code that you included now, fails for the reason that Jacob describes. Apparently both Jacob and I managed to misunderstand what you are trying to accomplish. At this stage, it is probably best if you update you question to include the code you are trying to execute and that fails.

Answer (score 1):

The reason things don't work as expected here is that [security rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter). Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely.

So, you would only be able to read from the `/events/` node if you can read every child of that node. So if you are not logged in or you are not logged in with the correct user, the read will fail.

To accomplish what you want, you should add an `/events/` node to each user in your `/users/` node which just list the eventId for each event they are a part of. Then you don't need you event query and can instead just easily get a users events by doing a read at `/users/$uid/events/`. Then you can look up the event details from the `/events/$eventId/` node and avoid any reads at the top-level `/events/` node which is disallowed by security rules.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm sorry but it seems that I turned my question badly, since it seems you didn't understand what I'm trying to do. Listing all the user's events is done somewhere else in my FB (I learned my lesson well, denormalized everything from the beginning), and I have absolutely no issue listing a user's events. What I'm struggling with is letting a user ADD a new event to that list. As I said in the question, for that, I should let the user search for the event by name, which is not possible with the current security rules - and I can't find how to.

Comment: If you are look to allow users to **add** data, but not overwrite existing data: `".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"` See also https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I already read all the docs carefully (and multiple times) ! I'm absolutely not trying to write anything, I'm trying to find the good security rule to GET data using orderByChild + equalTo queries while the parent location, which is the Firebase reference I use, is NOT readable.

Comment: The short answer is that using a query on a parent that is not readable is not allowed. You need to read directly from the children and find a different way to do the query. The way around that would be to store all the event IDs for each user and directly access each child event.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I guess there currently isn't any hidden security rule that works with queries :D I will find a workaround. Have a nice day !